# How can I scroll a buttons in horizontal scroll view (Android)?

Tags: android, button, horizontalscrollview

I want to scroll a five or more buttons in horizontal way like

There are five buttons 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5

```
           < 1  2  3  >
```

If click on button 2 then button 1 moves to left and invisible and button 4 comes to left and visible. Like this if clicked on button 3 then the buttons 1 and 2 are moves to left and invisible and then the buttons 4 and 5 are will comes and visible.

How can I implement this idea in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Gallery with list of button items..

It will be very good..for all your conditions.